# CSS3/JQuery wait for css to be applied

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I want to be able to slide in a div from either side of the page (this will eventually turn into a carousel-like application). when a user clicks the "forward" or "backward" button, I slide out any active divs, create a new div, add class "left" or "right" to it to start, then add the transition class "active" so it will move into place, like so:

```
$("#forward").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active left right").addClass("toRight").bind(transitionendstr, function(){
            $(this).remove();
    });

    data = "new data here";

    target = $(slidepartial).clone().addClass("left");
    $("#content").append(target);
    $(target).addClass("active");

});
```

where the css is:

```
.active{
left:50% !important;
transition:left 2s;
-moz-transition: left 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: left 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: left 2s; /* Opera */
}

.left{
left:-100%;
}

.right{
left:100%;
}

.toRight{
left:100%;
transition:left 2s;
-moz-transition: left 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: left 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: left 2s; /* Opera */

}


.toLeft{
left:-100%;
transition:left 2s;
-moz-transition: left 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: left 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: left 2s; /* Opera */

}
```

the only problem is, the new div I created never lets the "left" or "right" css take effect; it just immediately appears in the center. What's the proper way to make the left and right css apply before the active css does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a plug and play solution, but here is a sample to apply CSS transition on `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/VPjX9/193/

You could inspire you to fix your problem. The transition trigger is done by clicking on the `div` or a button, then the class is apply.
Have a look on the transitions classes in the fiddle for more details.

```
$('.page1, .page2, #go').click(function() {
    var page1 = $('.page1');
    var page2 = $('.page2');
    var toHide = page1.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;
    var toShow = page2.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;

    toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
    toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
});
```

​

Comment: thanks, I ended up adding "setTimeout(function(){$(target).addClass("active")},0);" instead of just "$(target).addClass("active")" to force the previous class to take effect before the transition started